# Issue regarding list_folder/continue in drop box

Tags: c#, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am using dropbox api endpoint list_folder/continue which is in help to get updated or edited files from dropbox account. But it is only fetching that files which are updated or creating on home location. It is not able to fetch updated files from sub folder

Comment: Paste an [mcve] so we can verify what you are doing, also paste the link to the api documentation for the exact call your are using and parameters. Also, consider reading [ask]

Comment: I am using https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-api-v2-explorer/#files_list_folder/continue api for getting updated files and folders from dropbox with access token and generated cursor but not able to get subfolders only able to fetch root folder

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Discuss-Dropbox-Developer-API/Regarding-list-folder-continue-in-drop-box/td-p/543258 ]